# How to filter unusefull data in a dataset using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter, dataset

I have a dataset : temperature and pressure values in different ranges.
I want to filter out all data that deviates more than x% from the "normal" value. This data occurs on process failures .

Extra: the normal value can change over a longer time , so what is a exception at timestamp1 can be normal at timestamp2.

I looked into some noise-filters but i'm not sure this is noise.

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions.

## 1.

Tack on a derived column, so it's easy to filter.

For "x%", like five percent, you might use

```
avg = np.mean(df.pressure)
df['pres_deviation'] = abs(df.pressure - avg) / avg
print(df[df.pres_deviation < .05])
```

But rather than working with a percentage,
you might find it more natural to work with standard deviations,
filtering out e.g. values more than three standard deviations from the mean.
See

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score
- sklearn [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)

## 2.

(Extra: the normal value can change over time.)

You could use a window of "most recent 100 samples" to define a smoothed average, store that as an extra column, and it replaces the `avg` scalar in the calculations above.

More generally you could manually set high / low thresholds as a time series in your data.

The area you're describing is called "change point detection", and we find an extensive literature on it, see e.g. https://paperswithcode.com/task/change-point-detection .
I have used [ruptures](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures/) to good effect, and I recommend it to you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If avg=15 and pressure=18 (more than 5%)  18-15/15=0.2 wich is still smaller than 1.05

Comment: Uggh, sorry. Updated the comparison.